# Is there an easy way to use symbols for footnotes in rmarkdown/bookdown?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, cpu-word, bookdown

I would like to use numbered references and symbols for footnotes in my Rmarkdown document. The bookdown package is excellent for the referencing and cross-referencing, etc. However, I can't find any easy way to change the footnote numbering to symbols. Is there an easy way (ideally to export as both Word and PDF)?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, it's as simple as adding

`header-includes:`
 `- \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}`

To the YAML.
Thanks to https://www.resurchify.com/latex_tutorial/latex_footnotes.php